# php ipn subscriptions advice

Tags: php, paypal

I've been looking all over the internet, played with ipn a bit, but can't figure out how to get paypal to work with subscriptions (monthly). Any advice on how to get monthly subscriptions to work, and update the database if they paid, or cancelled? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

[here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code_ipn_code_samples) is some sample code from paypal. Paypal gives you a return after the completion of the request. So you need a file on your webserver and paypal gives you automaticly a return to this file. Then you can insert it to your database.

And from your database you can generate reports. when you don't understand the example you should look more on php first.

I hop this was your question.

Comment: yeah I've seen this, but how do you make it work with subscriptions?

Comment: i think paypal call the file at the end of the month. But i remember you have to please the return file in the paypal admin. Perhaps you should use the sandbox and test all the cases and test what happen.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the txn_type's provided in https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables and https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/subscriptions/Appx-ipn_subscription_variables.html and code the IPN script accordingly. You should see these txn_type's in your subscription IPN's as well.

E.g.
if($_POST['txn_type'] == "recurring_payment") {
 // update database
}

Of course, you'll still need to POST the data back to PayPal in order to validate it. But checking the txn_type should give you enough granularity to update your database accordingly.
Keep in mind that 'subscriptions' starting with I- are actually 'recurring payments'. Subscriptions start with S-. These are legacy and thus you shouldn't see these any longer, but it's good to keep this in the back of your mind anyway.